# Display latex output natively in emacs in a vertically split window

Tags: latex, pdf

Running Doom Emacs 2.0.9 on Emacs 26.3.

Currenly, when I do `TeX-command-run-all` on a tex file, it opens the output in `okular` pdf viewer in a separate KDE window.

I was wondering if it is possible to have the output displayed natively in emacs in a vertically split window next to the tex file window.

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need something that renders pdf files in Emacs and plays well with Latex such as [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools). Then you'll need to setup [AucTex](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/auctex.html). Here are my configurations for both of these. Note that there maybe other possible configurations that achieve the same end result but since I have gotten this to work for me, I am sharing this,

```lisp
;; pdf-tools
(use-package pdf-tools
  :ensure t
  :init
  (pdf-tools-install))

;; auctex
(use-package auctex
  :ensure t 
  :after latex
  :init
  (setq tab-width 2 
        LaTeX-item-indent 0 latex "latex"
        pdf-latex-command "xelatex"
        TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Tools"))
        TeX-view-program-list
        '(("PDF Tools" TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view)))
  (setq-default TeX-engine 'xetex)
  (add-hook
   'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions
   #'TeX-revert-document-buffer)
  :hook
  ;; (TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions
  ;;  . TeX-revert-document-buffer)
  (LaTeX-mode .
              (lambda()
                (add-to-list
                 'TeX-command-list
                 '("XeLaTeX" "%`xelatex --synctex=1%(mode)%' %t"
                   TeX-run-TeX nil t))
                (setq TeX-command-default "XeLaTeX"
                      TeX-source-correlate-mode t)))
  :bind (:map LaTeX-mode-map
              ("C-c C-c" .
               (lambda (ARG)
                 (interactive "P")
                 (save-buffer)
                 (TeX-command-run-all ARG)))
              ("C-l <backspace>"
               . (lambda () 
                   (interactive) 
                   (TeX-clean) 
                   (message "Cleaned!")))))
```

You may want to adjust these as per your need and then try `C-c C-c`.